# DocumentDB Stored Procs: what does the EnableScriptLogging option do?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

The DocumentDB APIs for working with stored procedures take an optional `RequestOptions` argument that has, among others, the property `EnableScriptLogging`.

The [help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.requestoptions.enablescriptlogging.aspx) for it is useless. The description for it is:

> EnableScriptLogging is used to enable/disable logging in JavaScript stored procedures.

Mkay... so **how do I log something**? (assuming that's `console.log(...)`)
And more importantly, **how do I *read* the logs** generated by stored procedures?

I was expecting the `response` of requests to stored procedures would somehow contain the logs, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is for console.log from script. Must be enabled by client (turned off by default, so that console.log in script is ignored), essentially this set http-header on request. 
 In script you can do something like this:

```
function myScript() { 
  console.log("This is trace log");
}
```

The log will be in response header (x-ms-documentdb-script-log-results), as well as can be accessible in SDK.
If you use C# SDK, you can use it like this:

```
var options = new RequestOptions { EnableScriptLogging = true };
var response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(sprocUri, options);
Console.WriteLine(response.ScriptLog);
```

If you use node.js SDK:

```
var lib = require("documentdb");
var Client = lib.DocumentClient;
var client = new Client("https://xxxxxxx.documents.azure.com:443/", { masterKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxx" });
var sprocLink = ...;
client.executeStoredProcedure(sprocLink, "input params", { partitionKey: {}, enableScriptLogging: true }, function(err, res, responseHeaders) {
console.log(responseHeaders[lib.Constants.HttpHeaders.ScriptLogResults]);
}
```

Current limitations:

- only enabled for stored procedures
- \n is not supported (should be fixed soon)
- not supported when script throws unhandled exception (should be fixed soon)

Comment: This is great. Thanks! Where's the documentation for this?

Comment: good point, this should be part of SDK (xmldoc comments), I'll make sure it gets there.