# Microsoft Azure CosmostDB Script Explorer console.log

Tags: javascript, azure, console, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to debug a stored procedure or a script written in Microsoft Azure CosmosDB 'Script Explorer' using javascript. I put several console.log() messages so that I could trace my proc and I couldn't find where those log messages are written to.

On the script frame, there is a text box to enter your input variables and below that there is a text box which displays response.

Where do I find the log messages that I log using console.log()?

thanks.

Comment: Also please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610233/documentdb-stored-procs-what-does-the-enablescriptlogging-option-do) post.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a **getScriptLog** method to get the **console. Log ()** statement in the Azure Cosmos DB Stored Proceduce [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb._stored_procedure_response.getscriptlog).

I created a stored procudure in my Azure Cosmos DB Collection as below:

[image]

I don't know what language SDK you are currently using, please refer to the **Java SDK** sample code as below which could also be implemented in other SDKs.

```
//query exist stored procedure in collection
StoredProcedure createdSproc =documentClient.readStoredProcedure("dbs/" + DATABASE_ID + "/colls/" + COLLECTION_ID +"/sprocs/"+"test", null).getResource();
//print query result
System.out.println(createdSproc.toString());
try {
    //set Request options
    RequestOptions options=new RequestOptions();
    //enable script logging  true
    options.setScriptLoggingEnabled(true);
    //execute stored procedure
    StoredProcedureResponse spr = documentClient.executeStoredProcedure(createdSproc.getSelfLink(), options,
            null);
    System.out.println(spr.toString());
    System.out.println("status code: "+spr.getStatusCode());
    //print script log
    System.out.println("Scrpit Log: "+ spr.getScriptLog());
    System.out.println("Response body: "+spr.getResponseAsString());
} catch (DocumentClientException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Please note that this code is necessary to print console.log**:

> options.setScriptLoggingEnabled(true);

Comment: You could mark this answer for others' reference on the forum.Thx.